# Python - Powershell/CMD won't open interpreter at all

Tags: python, windows, powershell, cmd

I cannot run any program from shell, nor i can't open interpreter in it. There is no error, python just refuses to work. It worked correctly in the past so i don't know what could cause this behaviour, here is printscreen
[image]

Comment: Did you look for any log files that might tell you what's the problem here ... given how you got no err msg in the shell.

Comment: where would i find such log files?

Comment: Reinstall Python.

Comment: python itself works, i can run interpreter by running "Python 3.6 64-bit" program, it just wont run from cmd. Well i also cant run external python programs that i wrote in txt file, so its still quite a problem

Comment: Maybe python -v argument could shed more light on the issue. (verbose)

Comment: @λjk.jk - the fact that running `python` produces NO ERROR AT ALL means that _python ran and exited_. you will need to study your shortcut that DOES work and compare that to what happens if you go to the python dir and run `python` in a cmd or PoSh shell.

Comment: Maybe there's a startup script? Try running Python with `-S` to disable those.